# Creating PDFs in iTextSharp with Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, itext

I am looking to use itextSharp to create PDFs in my MVC 3 application, and I will be using Azure. What I would like to know is will this create a problem and does Azure support this function.

Answer (score -1):

You can pretty much run anything you want in azure so it wont be a problem from that prospective. The biggest thing to remember is that you probably won't want to perform such a heavy operation in a web role. A worker role is much better suited for this type of task. You could setup a system where you use Azure queues to request PDF jobs and the worker role reads the queue and runs these jobs. You shouldn't have any problem with that approach. Check out the Azure Toolkit to get you started: http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com